# Relaxation of requirements for Anderson's inequality

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

[Anderson's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%27s_theorem) states that for a nonnegative, symmetric, globally integrable and unimodal function $f$, i.e.

1. $f(x) \geq 0$,
2. $f(-x) = f(x)$,
3. $\int f(x) dx < \infty$
4. For all $t\in \mathbb R$, $\{x:~f(x)\geq t\}$ is convex,

we know that for any convex body $K$ with $-K = K$,
$$ \int_K f(x+cy)d x \geq \int_K f(x+y) d x$$

In the specific case of norm balls, i.e. $K = B_\delta(0) = \{x:~\|x\|<\delta\}$ (with an arbitrary norm), we get
$$\int_{B_\delta(cy)} f(z) dz \geq \int_{B_\delta(y)}f(z) dz$$

If we interpret $f$ as the density of a probability measure $\mu$, this means that
$$\mu(B_\delta(cy)) \geq \mu(B_\delta(y)),$$ i.e. translating a ball "inward" increases its probability mass.

Now I am interested in generalizing this by relaxing condition 4. In particular, I would like to consider the case where $f$ is still unimodal, but not in the sense that $f$ is quasiconcave, but "star-shaped" log-concave (there is probably an established name for this notion, but I don't know it), i.e.

**Alternative condition 4**. The mapping $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $\alpha\mapsto f(\alpha x)$ is log-concave for any $x$.

I have done a few experiments, specifically in the case $f(x) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 0.5\cdot(|x_1|+|x_2|)^2$ (which fulfills items 1--3, but is only "star-shaped log-concave" with non-convex level sets) and at least in this example, Anderson's inequality holds in all the cases I tried, i.e. the measure of the ball increases with translation towards the origin.

**Does anyone know any references regarding this generalization?**

[image]
[image: mass of ball is monotonous function of distance of ball to origin]

Comment: There are a number of things to address before this question is ready to be answered, including the following: (i) In Anderson's inequality, $|c|\le1$; (ii) in your second condition 4 (not a good idea to assign the same number to a different condition), the domain is not defined. Is it $\mathbb R$? Or $[0,\infty)$? Or something else? (iii) Anderson's condition 4 on $f$ is a concavity-type, not convexity-type, condition. E.g., it holds when $f$ is log concave.

Comment: Previous comment continued: So, your second condition 4 is kind of opposite to Anderson's condition 4. (iv) In the case $f(x) = x_1^2 + x_2^2-0.5\cdot(|x_1|+|x_2|)$ Anderson's condition 1 does not hold. Moreover, Anderson's conclusion $\int_K f(x)\,dx\ge\int_K f(x+y) \,dx$ will then fail to hold if $|y|$ is large enough.

Comment: I fixed i, ii, iii. I got confused here, thanks! Regarding iv): Why is condition 1 violated? By Hölder's inequality, $|x|+|y|\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot \sqrt{2}$, thus $x^2+y^2 - \frac{1}{2}(|x|+|y|)^2 \geq 0$, right? PS: Aha, I forgot the squares! Fixed that in the post. The simulations were done with the squares.

Comment: If now $f(x) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 0.5\cdot(|x_1|+|x_2|)^2$, then $f$ is not "star-shaped log-concave". In particular, $\mathbb R\ni s\mapsto f(s,0)$ is not log concave. Also, Anderson's conclusion will then still fail to hold if $|y|$ is large enough.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why Anderson's inequality is not true for $|y|$ large?

Comment: Because then $\int_{B_\delta(y)}f(z) dz\to\infty$ as $|y|\to\infty$. However, this is now irrelevant for two reasons: (i) that particular $f$ is not "star-shaped log-concave"; (ii) now there is an answer with an example of a "star-shaped log-concave" function for which the desired conclusion does not hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\de}{\delta}\newcommand{\ep}{\epsilon}$The answer is no. Indeed, the desired conclusion is that
\begin{equation}
    p(t):=\int_{ty+B}dx\,f(x)
\end{equation}
is monotonically (but possibly not strictly) decreasing in $t\ge0$, where $y\in\R^n$, $B$ is a symmetric convex subset of $\R^n$, and $f\colon\R^n\to\R$ satisfies the conditions 1, 2, 3 and the alternative condition 4.

Let $n=2$, $B:=[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$, $y:=(1,0)$, and
\begin{equation}
    f(x):=e^{-|u|}1(|v|<|u|/2)
\end{equation}
for all $x=(u,v)\in\R^2$. Then all the conditions on $f$, $B$, $y$ are satisfied.

However, for $t\in[0,1)$
\begin{equation}
    p(t)=\int_{t-1}^{t+1}du\,\int_{-|u|/2}^{|u|/2}dv\,e^{-|u|}
    =\int_{t-1}^{t+1}du\,|u|e^{-|u|}
\end{equation}
and hence
\begin{equation}
    p'(t)=|t+1|e^{-|t+1|}-|t-1|e^{-|t-1|},
\end{equation}
so that $p'(1-)=2e^{-2}>0$, which shows that $p(t)$ is not decreasing in $t\ge0$.